Does Wigner rotation mean that in special relativity it is possible to rotate an object without applying any torque to it?
Does Wigner rotation mean that in special relativity it is possible to rotate an object (change its orientation relative to the three spatial axes) without applying any torque to it?
It is assumed that the object is initially at rest in some inertial reference frame.
I would also try to formulate my question as follows for clarity:
Suppose that some spaceship moves with a constant proper acceleration provided by its engines (onboard accelerometers at different points in the spaceship show the same direction of proper acceleration).
Consider two inertial reference frames S and S' in a standard configuration, such that in frame S the spaceship moves rectilinearly in the direction of the y-axis (therefore in the S' frame the points of the spaceship trace hyperbolic trajectories).
Does the angular momentum of the spaceship change in the reference frames S and S'?
Does the inertia tensor of the spaceship change in the reference frames S and S'?

Yes, but I'd rather say that whether there is a classical "torque" is a frame-dependent question.
As a simple example, suppose we have a horizontal metal bar at rest, and at some moment, we apply an equal impulse to each end simultaneously. Then the bar will start moving up, and it won't be rotating because we applied no torque to it.
Now consider the same situation in a reference frame moving along the metal bar. By loss of simultaneity, the impulses won't happen at the same time, so between them the bar will rotate a bit. By going to a different frame, we've converted a situation with no angular impulse to a situation which does have one. This is the dynamical explanation of the Wigner rotation effect. You don't get any "magical" torque arising independent of any physical cause; instead it results from the ordinary forces that have to be present to cause acceleration in the first place.

Yes. Here's an example. Fly an airplane (or a spaceship if you prefer) around a circle. Inside the plane keep a rigid metal bar. Support the bar by forces in such a way that in the instantaneous rest frame there is no torque at any time. When the plane finishes the circle the bar will be rotated relative to its starting direction.
If you replace the bar by something having angular momentum, such as a gyroscope, and again support it without torque in each instantaneous rest frame, then it too will rotate. This implies there is a torque in any frame relative to which the gyroscope rotates. If you analyze carefully you will indeed find such a torque.
